# xsl copy if attribute of current node equals to attribute of another node

Tags: xslt, attributes, copy

I have a sample XML File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<XML>
    <MetaData>
        <Ref MDID='ID'></Ref>
    </MetaData>
    <MetaData2>
        <Ref MDID='ID2'></Ref>
    </MetaData2>
    <Items ID='ID'>
        <Item OID='haveit'></Item>
        <Item OID='ornot'></Item>
    </Items>
    <Items ID= ID2'>
        <Item OID='ornot'></Item>
        <Item OID='ornot'></Item>
    </Items>
</XML>
```

I have to transform it so that I receive the following result.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<XML>
    <MetaData>
        <Ref MDID='ID'></Ref>
    </MetaData>
    <Items ID='ID'>
        <Item OID='haveit'></Item>
    </Items>
</XML>
```

So first I have to check if the Item 'haveit' exists. Then I copy the corresponding parent "Item". Then I need to copy the MetaData where the MDID equals to the Items ID (in this case 'ID', but I don't know the exact value in my real example)
What I have so far:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />
    <xsl:variable name="Item" select = "'haveit'"/>
    <xsl:template match="XML">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Items">
        <xsl:if test="child::Item[@OID = $Item]">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:copy-of select="@*" /> <!-- copy attributes -->                                            
            </xsl:copy>             
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

With this code I'm able to copy the Item I want and the corresponding Items Element. Now I don't know how to get the right MetaData element. How can I check if the MDID of Ref hase the same value as the Items ID?

Comment: Are there really elements named `MetaData` and `MetaData2`?

Comment: Are you using an XSLT 1.0 or 2.0 processor?

Comment: I'm using XSLT 2.0. Yes this is just an example of the real data I have, but yes it's looking like this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:param name="oid" select="'haveit'"/>

<xsl:key name="meta" match="*" use="Ref/@MDID" />

<xsl:template match="/XML">
    <xsl:variable name="matching-items" select="Items[Item/@OID=$oid]" />
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="key('meta', $matching-items/@ID)"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="$matching-items"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Items">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="@*" />  
        <xsl:copy-of select="Item[@OID=$oid]" />                                         
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>    

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: thanks this one works, but now the order of the elements is not the same, can I predefine the order?

Comment: @user3891252 Just switch them around: do `<xsl:copy-of select="key('meta', $matching-items/@ID)"/>` before `<xsl:apply-templates select="$matching-items"/>`.

Comment: ok thanks a lot, just one more question, how can I make this work if there is another 'haveit' item within the <Items ID= ID2'> (so that the MetaData with MDID 'ID2' is copied too?

Comment: @user3891252 I have only now noticed that your `MetaData` elements have different names.  This *can* be solved, but I am not sure what in your example is given and  what's just an example. I have edited my answer, but there may be a more efficient solution.

Comment: @user3891252 Then my original version, using `"MetaData"` as the `match` attribute of the <key> element (instead of the generic `"*"`), would have worked. In XSLT, it's always best to be as explicit as you possibly can.